# How to know which thread completes execution first out of two threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I have two threads A and B. If A completes first, then I have to execute function1 else if B completes first, I need to execute function 2. HOw do I know which of the two threads has completed execution first?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Help needed in Multithreading to determing which thread stops first](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3381619/help-needed-in-multithreading-to-determing-which-thread-stops-first)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following which will only be set if the previous value was null. (This could be used even if you only have one thread to ensure a value is not changed once set)

```
AtomicReference<ValueType> ref = new AtomicReference<ValueType>();

ref.compareAndSet(null, value);
```

Comment: this is a good solution except that it doesn't allow the main thread to wait for the result.

Comment: No, but join() does that and is pretty standard. If you wanted to avoid using the join(), the waiting thread can busy wait or you could use a BlockingQueue with add() and take() to get the first answer and not wait for the additional threads to finish.

Answer (score 2):

```
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;

public class ThreadTest {
    private Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(0);
    private String winner;

    private synchronized void finished(String threadName) {
        if (winner == null) {
            winner = threadName;
        }
        semaphore.release();
    }

    public void run() {
        Runnable r1 = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep((long) (5000 * Math.random()));
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // ignore
                }
                finally {
                    finished("thread 1");
                }
            }
        };

        Runnable r2 = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep((long) (5000 * Math.random()));
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // ignore
                }
                finally {
                    finished("thread 2");
                }
            }
        };

        Thread t1 = new Thread(r1);
        Thread t2 = new Thread(r2);
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        try {
            semaphore.acquire();
            System.out.println("The winner is " + winner);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("No winner");
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ThreadTest().run();
    }
}
```

This solution has the advantage of having a winner as soon as the first thread finishes, instead of having to wait until all the threads are done.

**EDIT :**

Aa indicated by jtahlborn, `CountDownLatch` is a better abstraction for this problem. The same algorithm can thus be written as this :

```
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;

public class ThreadTest {
    private CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    private String winner;

    private synchronized void finished(String threadName) {
        if (winner == null) {
            winner = threadName;
        }
        latch.countDown();
    }

    public void run() {
        Runnable r1 = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep((long) (5000 * Math.random()));
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // ignore
                }
                finally {
                    finished("thread 1");
                }
            }
        };

        Runnable r2 = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep((long) (5000 * Math.random()));
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // ignore
                }
                finally {
                    finished("thread 2");
                }
            }
        };

        Thread t1 = new Thread(r1);
        Thread t2 = new Thread(r2);
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        try {
            latch.await();
            System.out.println("The winner is " + winner);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("No winner");
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ThreadTest().run();
    }
}
```

If you want to wait for the two threads to finish before displaying the winner, you just have to initialize the latch to 2 instead of 1.

Comment: i was going to vote this up as a good answer, but i'm not sure why you used semaphore instead of simple wait/notify.

Comment: @jtahlborn : because Semaphore offers a higher abstraction, than synchronized/wait/notify, and is thus safer and easier to use and understand.

Comment: actually, i think Semaphore is a more confusing abstraction that is often abused.  Semaphore is for the allocation of resources.  using it in this situation is more confusing than a simple wait/notify would be.  if you want a higher level abstraction, a CountDownLatch probably would have made more sense.

Answer (score 2):

One of (many) possible solutions. Have some shared flag variable

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

final AtomicInteger winner = new AtomicInteger(0);
```

Then at the end of thread's run() method call in first thread

```
winner.compareAndSet(0, 1);
```

in second thread

```
winner.compareAndSet(0, 2);
```

This way atomic integer will allow to set non zero value only in thread that calls compareAndSet first.

Then you may obtain execution result as winner index with

```
winner.get()
```

In production code I would suggest using some constants for initial value and thread indexes.